# PHP callback MySQL never returns a value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 callback methods that I use to validate user input, one that checks if the email exists in the DB and other to check if user exists. My email one works fine however username one NEVER executes correctly (as it never returns a user).

**Code of the username callback**

```
// username check in DB
    private function username($username, $fieldname){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string ($username);
        if(strlen ($username) > 3 && strlen ($username) <= 25){
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM pre_reg WHERE username =:username UNION SELECT username FROM personal WHERE username =:username";
            try{
                $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $user = $query->fetch();
                if($user){
                    $this->errors[] = 'Please try a different username!';
                    return FALSE;
                }else{
                    $this->username = $username;
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }catch (PDOException $e){
                $e->getMessage(); // Store to file
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

**Same code that checks emails that works fine**

```
//email check
    private function email($email, $fieldname){
        $valid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if(!$valid){
            $this->errors[] = "We find your entery to be an invalid email address!";
        }
        if($valid && strlen($email) <= 40){
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string ($email);
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM pre_reg WHERE email =:email UNION SELECT email FROM personal WHERE email=:email";
            try{
                $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $user = $query->fetch();
                if($user){
                    $this->errors[] = 'Please try a different email address!';
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }catch (PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage(); // Store to file
            }

        }
        $this->email = $email;
        return TRUE;
    }
```

**This is how I am calling them**

```
// Validate all the data 
    public function validate($data, $rules){
        $valid = TRUE;
        foreach($rules as $fieldname => $rule){
            $callbacks = explode('|', $rule);
            foreach($callbacks as $callback){
                $value = isset($data[$fieldname]) ? $data[$fieldname] : NULL;
                if($this->$callback($value, $fieldname) == FALSE){
                    $valid = false;
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using mysql functions in PDO?

Comment: I have solved it once I figured out how to print the errors to see what is happening.. I was referencing a wrong table in my SQL statement and it was crashing but I couldn't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps I took to solve it:

echo this statement

```
catch (PDOException $e){
  $e->getMessage(); // Store to file
}
```

It showed me that there was no COLUMN in the table, once I wen't back and looked at my statement I realized I was calling a wrong table here :

```
UNION SELECT username FROM personal WHERE username =:user"
```

I was trying to actually call :

```
UNION SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =:user"
```

The reason I got this error is because I copy pasted the code from the email function and forgot to change the table. Keep that in mind for the next time!

Thanks for help!